# Do not allow to end action until both inputs have the same password

Tags: javascript, html

I am validating the password change fields. I start by forcing you to enter the current password. Then the user has to fill in the new password field where he has requirements to fulfill this way:

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("senhanova");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

myInput.onkeyup = function() {

  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
   var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  var upperCaseLetters = /[@$!%*?&]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    caracter.classList.remove("invalid");
    caracter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    caracter.classList.remove("valid");
    caracter.classList.add("invalid");
  }


  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  

  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}


/* Style the container for inputs */
.alteracao {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
}
    
.alteracao-signin {
  max-width: 420px;
  padding: 15px 35px 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.alteracao-signin-heading {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✖";
}

.input-icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: calc(50% - 0.5em); /* Keep icon in center of input, regardless of the input height */
}
input{
  padding-left: 17px;
}
.input-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>


<div class="alteracao">
    <form class="alteracao-signin" method="POST">
        <h2 class="alteracao-signin-heading">Tem de alterar a sua senha.</h2>
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhaatual" name="senhaatual" placeholder="Senha Atual" required><label for="senhaatual" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhanova" name="senhanova" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$" title="Deve conter pelo menos um número, uma letra maiúscula e minúscula, um caractere especial e pelo menos 8 ou mais caracteres" placeholder="Nova Senha" required><label for="senhanova" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhaconfir" name="senhaconfir" placeholder="Confirmar Senha" required><label for="senhaconfir" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="inserir_senha();">Alterar</button> 
  </form>
</div>

<div id="message">
  <h3>A senha deve conter o seguinte:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>letra </b> minúscula</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>letra </b> maiúscula</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">O <b>número</b></p>
  <p id="caracter" class="invalid">O <b>Caracter</b> especial</p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimo <b>8 caracteres</b></p>
</div>
```

The problem that exists is that after filling in the new password field fulfilling the requirements, if the user in the password confirmation field does not enter the same password as the previous field, the action ends.

I intend to only let the action finish after the new password and password confirmation fields are filled with the same passwords.

Comment: I think the problem is in the event (onkeyup) you used, try https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp to see more input events. I think onkeypress might suit your need, if not I offer you my apology.

Comment: @Randi Pratama Onkeypress also ends the action even if the passwords are different. It should only go forward after passwords are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyup` event to check the values of both the fields and enable or disable the button.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("senhanova");
var confirm = document.getElementById("senhaconfir");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

myInput.onkeyup = function() {

  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
   var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  var upperCaseLetters = /[@$!%*?&]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    caracter.classList.remove("invalid");
    caracter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    caracter.classList.remove("valid");
    caracter.classList.add("invalid");
  }


  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  

  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}

function inserir_senha () {
}

confirm.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  if (myInput.value != confirm.value) {
    document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }  
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}


/* Style the container for inputs */
.alteracao {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
}
    
.alteracao-signin {
  max-width: 420px;
  padding: 15px 35px 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.alteracao-signin-heading {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✖";
}

.input-icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: calc(50% - 0.5em); /* Keep icon in center of input, regardless of the input height */
}
input{
  padding-left: 17px;
}
.input-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>


<div class="alteracao">
    <form class="alteracao-signin" method="POST">
        <h2 class="alteracao-signin-heading">Tem de alterar a sua senha.</h2>
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhaatual" name="senhaatual" placeholder="Senha Atual" required><label for="senhaatual" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhanova" name="senhanova" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$" title="Deve conter pelo menos um número, uma letra maiúscula e minúscula, um caractere especial e pelo menos 8 ou mais caracteres" placeholder="Nova Senha" required><label for="senhanova" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhaconfir" name="senhaconfir" placeholder="Confirmar Senha" required><label for="senhaconfir" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="inserir_senha();">Alterar</button> 
  </form>
</div>

<div id="message">
  <h3>A senha deve conter o seguinte:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>letra </b> minúscula</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>letra </b> maiúscula</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">O <b>número</b></p>
  <p id="caracter" class="invalid">O <b>Caracter</b> especial</p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimo <b>8 caracteres</b></p>
</div>
```